# Controller function, calls another controller and replaces HTML Template

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular and I have hit a wall. What I am trying to achieve is once I click on an Item in the table in my HTML via data-ng-click.

This function, makes the call to second controller and instantiates the template and gets the data from the server. And replaces the ng-view. I am not sure how to instantiate this second controller from the partial1 view.

The behaviour I am after is like in this Angular Docs. But I would like this to happen through a function click on an Item in the table.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

However I am stuck on how to do this? If this possible?

App

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/Product', {
            templateUrl: '/Product/Index',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
        }).
    when('/GetProducts', {
        templateUrl: '/Product/ProductsTemplate',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    }).
    when('/GetReciepe', {
        templateUrl: '/Product/ReciepeTemplate',
        controller: 'testCtrl2'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

Controller1(testCtrl)

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/Product/GetProducts').success(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });

$scope.test = function test(){
//call controller 2 - which fetches data and gets another template
}
    }]);
```

Controller2(testCtrl2)

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl2', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.test = function test(product) {

            $http.get('/Product/GetReciepe?productId=' + product.ProductID).success(function (data) {
                $scope.reciepes = data;
            });
        }
    }]);
```

Index(Main view)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="row" style="margin:5px;">
        <a ng-href="/Product/GetProducts" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Test</a>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Partial(1)

```
<div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div>
        <label>Search:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>   
     <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">

                <tr>
                    @*<th>id</th>*@
                    <th>PIZZA</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products" data-ng-click="test(p);">
                    <td><h2>{{p.Description | uppercase}}</h2></td>
                    <td><img ng-src="{{p.ImageUrl}}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Partial(2) << to be placed in ng view to replace partial 1

```
<div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="r in reciepes">
            {{r.Description}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should consider making a service for this task, a service for doing http calls. Someone correct me if im wrong

Comment: Yes, that is the correct method. But I am trying to do this in simple steps first as I am learning and then branch it out to a service. @luk492

Comment: I'm also learning angular. Good luck with it.

Comment: thanks you too! @luk492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use **route params**.

make this change in App

```
when('/GetReciepe/:productID', {
    templateUrl: '/Product/ReciepeTemplate',
    controller: 'testCtrl2'
})
```

And in Partial(1)

```
           <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products">
                <td><h2>{{p.Description | uppercase}}</h2></td>
                <td><img ng-src="{{p.ImageUrl}}" /></td>
                <td><a href="#/GetReciepe/:{{ p.ID }}">view reciepe</a></td>
            </tr>
```

then use the route param inside testCtrl2

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl2', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams',
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    var getproductID= $routeParams.productID;
    $scope.test = function (product) {
        $http.get('/Product/GetReciepe?productId=' + getproductID).success(function (data) {
            $scope.reciepes = data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Tips:

- Execute your http calls inside a Factory/Service as rightly pointed out in comments
- `<div data-ng-controller="testCtrl">` is not needed as you have already bound your views and controllers using route provider.

Comment: @Harry Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and after tweaking it has worked for me. But yes, I agree correct method is to create a service and inject that into the controller.